# Is there any equivalent of C# Guid.Empty in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there any equivalent of C# `Guid.Empty` in Kotlin?

There seems nothing like that in Java.

Comment: Kotlin is also JVM based as Java, what you can do in JAVA can be done in Kotlin. below are the good answer s or you can generate random UUID by `UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();`

Answer (score 5):

There is UUID class in java. So, do this:

```
import java.util.*

UUID(0L, 0L) // This is like Guid.Empty in C#
```